# SimpleInjector.ActivationException with Simple Injector on SignalrR

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, signalr, signalr-hub, simple-injector

I Implemented the answer on [Using Simple Injector with SignalR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555791/using-simpleinjector-with-signalr) and my services are successfully resolved, not until `OnDisconnected` is called on the Hub class. Then I had to follow this question [Simple Injector per-web-api-request dependency in SignalR hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31895630/simple-injector-per-web-api-request-dependency-in-signalr-hub) as a workaround but get an exception whenever the hub instance is requested.

I get the exception saying:

> [SimpleInjector.ActivationException] The registered delegate for type ChatHub threw an exception. The ChatHub is registered as 'Hybrid Web Request / Execution Context Scope' lifestyle, but the instance is requested outside the context of a Hybrid Web Request / Execution Context Scope.

StackTrace:

```
at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.GetInstance()
at SimpleInjector.Container.GetInstance(Type serviceType)
at QuickChat.Hubs.SimpleInjectorHubActivator.Create(HubDescriptor descriptor) in c:\Users\Peter\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\QuickChat\QuickChat\Hubs\SimpleInjectorHubActivator.cs:line 21
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.DefaultHubManager.ResolveHub(String hubName)
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.CreateHub(IRequest request, HubDescriptor descriptor, String connectionId, StateChangeTracker tracker, Boolean throwIfFailedToCreate)

InnerException: 

at SimpleInjector.Scope.GetScopelessInstance[TService,TImplementation](ScopedRegistration`2 registration)
at SimpleInjector.Scope.GetInstance[TService,TImplementation](ScopedRegistration`2 registration, Scope scope)
at SimpleInjector.Advanced.Internal.LazyScopedRegistration`2.GetInstance(Scope scope)
at lambda_method(Closure )
at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.GetInstance()
```

See below my current code configs.
Hub activator:

```
public class SimpleInjectorHubActivator : IHubActivator
{
    private readonly Container _container;

    public SimpleInjectorHubActivator(Container container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public IHub Create(HubDescriptor descriptor)
    {
        return (IHub)_container.GetInstance(descriptor.HubType);
    }
}
```

SimpleInjector service registration:

```
public class SimpleInjectorConfig
{
    public static void Register()
    {
        // Create the container as usual.
        var container = new Container();

        var hybrid = Lifestyle.CreateHybrid(
            () => container.GetCurrentExecutionContextScope() != null,
            new SimpleInjector.Integration.Web.WebRequestLifestyle(),
            new ExecutionContextScopeLifestyle());

        // Register types:
        container.RegisterSingle<MembershipRebootConfiguration>(MembershipRebootConfig.Create);
        container.Register<DefaultMembershipRebootDatabase>(() => new CustomMembershipRebootDatabase());
        container.Register<UserAccountService>(() => new UserAccountService(container.GetInstance<MembershipRebootConfiguration>(), container.GetInstance<IUserAccountRepository>()));
        container.Register<AuthenticationService, SamAuthenticationService>();
        container.RegisterPerWebRequest<IUserAccountQuery, DefaultUserAccountRepository>();
        container.RegisterPerWebRequest<IUserAccountRepository, DefaultUserAccountRepository>();

        container.Register(() => new DataAccess.EF.DataContext(), hybrid);
        container.Register<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(hybrid);
        container.Register<IUserService, UserService>(hybrid);

        //Register SimpleAuthentication callback provider class
        container.RegisterPerWebRequest<IAuthenticationCallbackProvider, SimpleAuthenticationProviderController>();
        //Register SimpleAuthentication MVC controller.
        container.RegisterPerWebRequest<SimpleAuthenticationController>(
            () => new SimpleAuthenticationController(container.GetInstance<IAuthenticationCallbackProvider>(), null));

        // This is an extension method from the integration package.
        container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        // This is an extension method from the integration package as well.
        container.RegisterMvcIntegratedFilterProvider();
        //Enable injections to SignalR Hubs
        var activator = new SimpleInjectorHubActivator(container);
        container.Register<ChatHub, ChatHub>(hybrid);
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IHubActivator), () => activator);

        container.Verify();
        //Set dependency resolver for MVC
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
    }
}
```

Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        SimpleInjectorConfig.Register();
        // Register the default hubs route: ~/signalr/hubs
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Steven said in his answer, my hybrid lifestyle is wrong. I had to turn the predicate around:

```
var hybrid = Lifestyle.CreateHybrid(
() => container.GetCurrentExecutionContextScope() != null,
new ExecutionContextScopeLifestyle(),
new SimpleInjector.Integration.Web.WebRequestLifestyle());
```

After a few discussions with Steven [GitHub](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/141) I arrived at a conclusion.

I had to make my `ChatHub` a [Humble Object](http://xunitpatterns.com/Humble%20Object.html) and extract all logic from it and put into a separate class that implements a service interface consisting of methods that expose all the logic contained initially within the `ChatHub`

```
public interface IChatService
{
    void OnConnected(Guid userId, string connectionId, HubConnectionContext clients);
    void OnDisconnected(Guid userId, string connectionId);
    void Broadcast(string message, string username, HubConnectionContext clients);
}

public class ChatService : IChatService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    public UserChatService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public void OnConnected(Guid userId, string connectionId, HubConnectionContext clients) { 
        //Perform other operation using _unitOfWork
    }
    public void OnDisconnected(Guid userId, string connectionId) {
        //Perform other operation using _unitOfWork
    }
    public void Broadcast(string message, string username, HubConnectionContext clients) { 
        //Perform other operation using _unitOfWork and HubConnectionContext
        //broadcast message to other connected clients
        clients.others.broadcast(message);
    }
}
```

The `HubConnectionContext` really seems like runtime data to me, so I decided to pass it as a params to the methods.

With this, my hub `ChatHub` looks lightweight, delegating the calls to the `ChatService` object, and I no longer experience errors when the hub's `OnDisconnected()` is called .

And don't forget to register your service with the container:

```
container.Register<IChatService, ChatService>(hybrid);
```

Comment: This (and the Github link) form a superb answer - I was having the same issue and taking the time to structure my Hub implementation properly sorted out the OnDisconnect exception that was being thrown. Thanks for the complete sample.

Comment: pmbanugo, do you have a full example of it? i'm stuck at this
Thank you

Comment: @rsegovia I've created this [github gist](https://gist.github.com/pmbanugo/99933fc8ec58e96e8e6a7f972ed9e5be). it should help. Don't forget to vote up the question and answer if it was helpful to you. goodluck..

Answer (score 2):

Your hybrid lifestyle is wrong. You should turn the predicate around:

```
var hybrid = Lifestyle.CreateHybrid(
    () => container.GetCurrentExecutionContextScope() != null,
    new ExecutionContextScopeLifestyle(),
    new SimpleInjector.Integration.Web.WebRequestLifestyle());
```

Tip: instead of reusing that `hybrid` variable throughout your composition root, you can also set it as the default scoped lifestyle like this:

```
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = hybrid;
```

This way you can change your registrations to the following:

```
container.Register<ChatHub, ChatHub>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

This makes your registrations easier and cleaner.

Comment: I still an error but that's just swapping the predicate around just like you said, and without the `DefaultScopedLifestyle` code statement. Do I need to install this package `SimpleInjector.Extensions.LifetimeScoping` ? I can't find a definition for `Lifestyle.Scoped` and DefaultScopedLifestyle.

Comment: The `Lifestyle.Scoped` and `Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle` are new in Simple Injector v3. You are probably still working with v2, aren't you? You don't need the `LifetimeScoping` package *at all* in your case. Note that the use of `Lifestyle.Scoped` and `Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle` is completely optional; it's just cleaner IMO.

Comment: Is the new exception completely the same?

Comment: the error occurs only when a user is disconnecting from the Hub

Comment: @pmbanugo: Ahh... that's an old problem. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18487801/264697). It exactly explains the problem and the solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94218/discussion-between-pmbanugo-and-steven).